# Can I use a for loop for mj-carousel

Tags: mailjet

I am trying to have a for loop for the mj-carousel. Can't get it to work. Does mjml support this?

I have already tried to put for loop inside mj-carousel

```
        <mj-carousel icon-width="34px">
          {% for item in var:order.items %}
          <mj-carousel-image alt="{{item.name}}" title="{{item.name}}" thumbnails-src="{{item.image}}" src="{{item.md_image}}" href="{{var:cart_link}}" />
           {% endfor %}
        </mj-carousel>
```

Expect to see one mj-carousel-image for each item in order.items array.

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed use conditional statements for the carousel function within MJML the thing is that you have to use the condition before the `<mj-carousel>` tag. Below I am attaching a quick example of the Template along with the Send API Call so to give it a try.

**Template Example in MJML**

```
<mjml>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-section>
      <mj-column>
        {% for item in var:items %}
        <mj-carousel>
          <mj-carousel-image src="{{var:items.image1}}" />
          <mj-carousel-image src="{{var:items.image2}}" />
          <mj-carousel-image src="{{var:items.image3}}" />
        </mj-carousel>
        {% endfor %}
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

**Send API Call, vars section**

```
"Variables": {
"items": {
"image1":"https://www.mailjet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/ecommerce-guide.jpg", 
"image2":"https://www.mailjet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/3@1x.png", 
"image3":"https://www.mailjet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/1@1x.png"
         }                        
             }
```

I hope that helps you on this one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Krass, this can be achieved without that for loop. After I have tried many things, I confirm that it's impossible to do a for loop inside carousel. We have to figure out something else.
```<mjml>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-section>
      <mj-column>
        <mj-carousel>
          <mj-carousel-image src="{{var:items.image1}}" />
          <mj-carousel-image src="{{var:items.image2}}" />
          <mj-carousel-image src="{{var:items.image3}}" />
        </mj-carousel>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>```